# clojurescript / hiccup - inline css to set dispatch to a hover action

Tags: css, clojure, clojurescript, re-frame, hiccup

I'm trying to hover a text and change the **:display** of another text to **none**, in order to make it disappear. I've used **:onMouseOver**, but it does not work because it needs this.value I think.
So, any idea for how I can do that? I require inline CSS in this case.

This is what I have:

```
[:p {:onMouseOver #(rf/dispatch [:events/hover-feedback])} "hello"]
[:p {:style {:display @(rf/subscribe [::subs/hover-feedback])}} "world"]
```

And in events file:

```
(rf/reg-event-db
  ::hover-feedback
  (fn [db]
    (assoc db :hover-feedback "none")))
```

In subs file:

```
(rf/reg-sub ::hover-feedback (fn [db] (get-in db [:hover-feedback]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot one colon in the first `:p` dispatch. Try this:

Views:

```
[:p {:on-mouse-over #(rf/dispatch [::events/hover-feedback])}
             "hello"]
[:p {:style {:display @(rf/subscribe [::subs/hover-feedback])}}
             "world"]
```

Events (without change):

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
  ::hover-feedback
  (fn [db]
      (assoc db :hover-feedback "none")))
```

Subs (unnecessary `get-in`):

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
  ::hover-feedback
  (fn [db]
      (:hover-feedback db)))
```

Comment: It still does not work for me.

Comment: But it helped, thank you. The way I used "onMouseOver" was wrnong.